# How to calculate values row wise using lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

So I have a dataframe where I want to count all the days a student was present. The dataframe headers are the days of the month and I want to count the frequency of the character `'P'` row wise over all the columns and store them in a new column. What I have done unti now is defined a function which should accept each row and count the frequency of P -

```
def count_P(list):
    frequency = 0
    for item in list:
        if item == 'P':
            frequency += 1
    return frequency
```

And then I am trying to apply this function which is what I am confused about:

```
df['Attendance'] = df.apply(lambda x: count_P(x) for x in , axis = 1)
```

In the above line I need to pass x everytime as a row of the dataframe so do I write
`for x in range(df.iloc[0],df.iloc[df.shape[0]])`? But that gives me `SyntaxError`. And do I need axis here? Or does it need to be done in some other way?

Edit:
The error message I am getting-

```
df['Attendance'] = df.apply(lambda x: count_P(x) for x in range(df.iloc[0],df.iloc[df.shape[0]]),axis=1)
                                ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Comment: A sample dataframe would help a lot

Comment: A complete error message with traceback is also typically helpful

Comment: `df.head(10)` please.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Off-site links and [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Prune Do you mean I should post it as a text?

Comment: As text for a start, but we still expect you to follow the rest of the posting guidelines, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2021-03-01': ['P','P'], '2021-03-02': ['P','X']})
```

You can do :

```
df["p_count"] = (df == 'P').sum(axis=1)
```

yields:

```
    2021-03-01  2021-03-02  p_count
0   P           P           2
1   P           X           1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why I was making it so complex...